# Erro ao iniciar spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

O console apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
>       at com.example.demo.GerencieAppApplication.main(GerencieAppApplication.java:10)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 1 more

Comment: Acho que está faltando alguma dependência. Tente criar um novo projeto utilizando o https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tive este problema, geralmente falta de dependência ou configuração errada do repositório local maven, tente apagar as dependências relacionadas ao Spring Boot e importar o projeto novamente para que as dependências possam ser atualizadas. Geralmente o repositório local fica em seu diretório de usuário, na pasta `.m2/repository`.